# Firebase login with Twitter account is opening browser instead of the Twitter app

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I got an issue like this. Any body got the same?

### Environment

```
Xcode version: 13.3
Firebase SDK version: 6.8.1
Firebase Component: Auth
SwiftUI
iOS 14.0+
```

### Describe the problem

Firebase login with Twitter account is opening browser instead of the Twitter app.
[image: IMG_EEF148E3BE3E-1]

### Steps to reproduce:

- Installed Twitter app on IphoneX
- Logged in to Twitter already

Follow guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login

```
provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
      if error != nil {
        // Handle error.
      }
      if credential != nil {
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in

        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare in global scope like below

```
   var provider: OAuthProvider?
   func signInWithTwitter(){
   provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")
    provider?.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
      if error != nil {
        // Handle error.
          print("Error")
      }
      if credential != nil {
          Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential!) { authResult, error in
          if error != nil {
            // Handle error.
              print(error)
          }
              print(authResult?.user.displayName)
              
          // User is signed in.
          // IdP data available in authResult.additionalUserInfo.profile.
          // Twitter OAuth access token can also be retrieved by:
          // (authResult.credential as? OAuthCredential)?.accessToken
          // Twitter OAuth ID token can be retrieved by calling:
          // (authResult.credential as? OAuthCredential)?.idToken
          // Twitter OAuth secret can be retrieved by calling:
          // (authResult.credential as? OAuthCredential)?.secret
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code as below.

```
func twitterLogin()-> [String: Any]{
//create an object of provider
var provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")
provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
        
          //Check if any error
          if error != nil {
            // Handle error.
              result(["error":"Error occurred - unable to get credentials."]);
          }
          
          // Check if credential is not nil
          if credential != nil {
              
              // Sign in with credential
              Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential!)
              { authResult, error in
                  
                  // Check for any error while signing in with credentials
                  if error != nil {
                      result(["success":false, "message": "Error occurred while signing in."]);
                  }
                  
                  // Get id token of the current logged in user
                  authResult!.user.getIDToken { (idToken, error) in
                      
                         // Check for any error while getting idToken for the signed in user
                         if let error = error {
                             result(["success":false, "message":"Unable to get id token"]);
                         }
                      
                         // Get oAuthCredentials
                          var oAuth = authResult?.credential as?  OAuthCredential
                         
                         // Check if oAuth is null or not
                          if(oAuth == nil){
                              result(["success":false, "message":"Unable to resolve auth credential."]);
                          }
                         // Generate map or dictionary to send the response to the result callback
                      
                          var response = [String: Any]()
                          response["profile"] = authResult?.additionalUserInfo?.profile
                          response["idToken"] = idToken
                          response["accessToken"] = oAuth?.accessToken
                          response["success"] = true
                          response["message"] = "Successfully logged in"
                          
                          result(response)
                     }
            
                 
              // User is signed in.
              // IdP data available in authResult.additionalUserInfo.profile.
              // Twitter OAuth access token can also be retrieved by:
              // (authResult.credential as? OAuthCredential)?.accessToken
              // Twitter OAuth ID token can be retrieved by calling:
              // (authResult.credential as? OAuthCredential)?.idToken
              // Twitter OAuth secret can be retrieved by calling:
              // (authResult.credential as? OAuthCredential)?.secret
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Just use function and it will return the response after handling all the exceptions.