# Twitter App is not opening for "login with twitter" in iOS with Firebase authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

We have integrated login with twitter using Firebase. We have followed all the steps as mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login

However when we call that method a webview is opening in iOS instead of Twitter app. Is there any way we can force to open the app if app is installed? I have already added twitter and twitterauth to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in the Info.plist. But none works. Any suggestions will help us. Thanks

There is a similar question asked here but no answers, so asking again [Firebase login with Twitter account is opening browser instead of the Twitter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72796485/firebase-login-with-twitter-account-is-opening-browser-instead-of-the-twitter-ap)

Comment: I am not sure if you can open the Twitter app for signing in. It should always open the WebView. Have you tried reaching out to Twitter Developers community?

Comment: i see same problem. No solution yet. Nothing happens when i execute the code from that tutorial